# fit all the inner tags inside their container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a explain bubble and I want to put some text like p tags and spans and img tags inside the `explain-header` div as the container of my explanations:

```css
/*Explain Bubble*/
.explain-container {
  position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 70vw;
  max-height: 50vh;
  background-color: rgba(6, 0, 15, 0.4);
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.125rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0 0.0625rem 0.125rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.explain-header {
  padding: 1em 1em;
  color: #e9e4f0;
}

#phrase {
  font-family: "Open Sans Bold";
   color: #ff9100;
}

#colon {
  font-family: "Open Sans Regular";
  color: #ff0033;
}

#en-definition{
  font-family: "Open Sans Light";
   color: #f0ede9;
}

html{
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-user-select: none; 
  user-select: none;
}

body {
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0px!important;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
  height: 100vh;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="explain-container">

        <div class="explain-header">
            <span id="phrase">make up</span>
            <span id="colon">:</span>
            <span id="en-definition">to prepare for sth</span>
            <p>Nick made up a song about them.
             When you’re the boss you can make up your own rules.
             I’ve given talks so many times that now I just make them up as I go along (=think of things to say as I amNick made up a song about them.
             When you’re the boss you can make up your own rules.
             I’ve given talks so many times that now I just make them up as I go along (=think of things to say as I amNick made up a song about them.
             When you’re the boss you can make up your own rules.
             I’ve given talks so many times that now I just make them up as I go along (=think of things to say as I amNick made up a song about them.
             When you’re the boss you can make up your own rules.
             I’ve given talks so many times that now I just make them up as I go along (=think of things to say as I am
            Nick made up a song about them.
             When you’re the boss you can make up your own rules.
             I’ve given talks so many times that now I just make them up as I go along (=think of things to say as I am
             Nick made up a song about them.
             When you’re the boss you can make up your own rules.
             I’ve given talks so many times that now I just make them up as I go along (=think of things to say as I am
            Nick made up a song about them.
             When you’re the boss you can make up your own rules.
             I’ve given talks so many times that now I just make them up as I go along (=think of things to say as I am THIS IS THE LAST LINE WHICH SHOULD BE VISIBLE
             </p>
        </div>

    </div>
```

So far when the explanations are long they overflow the container and user wouldn't able to read them all.

How can we fit all the explanations inside the container. by reducing the font size or expanding the height of the container maybe?

Comment: Well either don’t set a max-height, or apply overflow:auto instead of hidden?

Comment: The best way would be is to make the container reasize by its content, that mean that the container will fitt its content and exapand. the other way is to make it scrollable

Comment: I don't want scroll bar here ... the content wouldn't be so long... if I could expand the container by the content...

Answer (score -1):

you are using fixed height and for show all elements (seems they are too much) if you dont want use `overflow:auto` best thing you can do is put button or link (example title: show more) inside the bubble with inline popup window (https://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/GEKgb)

Comment: she want " fit all the explanations inside the container"  container has  max-width: 70vw;
  max-height: 50vh; so its impossible!